# $G$ is abelian when any two non-identity $a$ , $b$ there is an automorphism $\delta$ such that $\delta(a)=b.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, proof-writing

$G$  is a  finite  group with identity  $\mathcal e.$  Suppose  for any  two non-identity elements $a$ , $b$ of $G$ , there is an automorphism $\delta$ such that  $\delta(a)=b.$ Then prove that $G$ is abelian .

So what I was thinking to do is that $$a\cdot b=b\cdot a$$
By the given condition there is a $\delta$ such that $$\delta(a\cdot b)=b\cdot a\\or,\ \ \ \delta(a)\cdot \delta(b)=b\cdot a.$$

Now I don't know what to do next .

Also another thing that I observed was that for any non-identity element $a$, there is a automorphism $\phi$ such that $$a=\phi(a^2)\\={(\phi(a))}^2$$  and  thus every *non-identity* element of $G$ is a **square.**  Then we have $$a=a_1^2=a_2^4=a_3^8=.............=a_n^{2^n}=..$$  But for finiteness  of  $G$  this  has  to  stop  somewhere.  I supposed that  might  be  helpful  in  some ways  but  could  not figure  out  what  conclusions  might  be  drawn  from  that either .

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, observe that all elements have the same order and this order must be a prime number $p$ (this follows from Cauchy's Theorem and the fact that $Aut(G)$ acts transitively on $G - \{1\}$).

So $G$ is a $p$-group, and hence does have a non-trivial center. Pick $z \in Z(G)$, $z \neq 1$. Let $a,b \in G$. Then there exists a $\delta \in Aut(G)$ with $\delta(a)=z$. But then $\delta(ab)=z\delta(b)=\delta(b)z=\delta(ba)$. Since $\delta$ is injective it follows that $ab=ba$, whence $G$ is abelian. It even follows that $G \cong C_p \times \cdots \times C_p$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: $\phi(a).\phi(b)=\phi(a.b)=b^{-1}.a^{-1}=.$  Sorry  I  did  not  understand , what  is  the  other   way  $?$

Comment: @user118494 $\phi(a b) = \phi(a) \phi(b) = a^{-1} b^{-1}.$

Comment: Well $\phi(ab)=(ab)^{-1}$, can you take it from here?

Comment: @user118494 I was just wondering - you don't mean $\delta$ to be dependent on each pair $a, b \in G$?

Comment: @NickyHekster : Actually, I do . As the question puts it " For  each pair $a$ , $b$ there  is a  $\delta$ "  - looked  like  *dependence* to me.

Comment: @IgorRivin : Actually the question says " For every non-identity  pair $a\neq b$ there is a  $\delta$ "  so from that I have $\phi$  for  $a.b$  and $(a.b)^{-1}$  and , say , $\mu $ for $a$ and $a^{-1}$ . How can I say  $\mu=\phi$ $?$

Comment: @IgorRivin and user118494 - I made a correction, apologies for the confusion!